# Código para enviar mensagem para email por botão de Enviar

Tags: php, html5, css3

Já tenho o formulário com a caixa de mensagem e etc, também já tenho o botão de enviar, mas preciso do código para quando clicar em enviar, a mensagem ser enviada para determinado e-mail.

Meu código:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="name" placeholder="Seu Nome">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="email" placeholder="Seu E-mail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="subject" placeholder="Assunto">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <textarea name="message" cols="1" rows="1" class="message" placeholder="Sua mensagem..." id="message"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Enviar Mensagem" id="submit" class="button templatemo_sendbtn">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: se a minha resposta nao ajudar, voce poderia colocar seu codigo ? seria mais facil ajuda voce dessa forma.

Answer (score 2):

Vou te explicar como vai ficar para funcionar, você pode [dar uma lida sobre a função `mail`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php) para entender melhor depois.

Supomos que sua página seja `index.html` ou `contato.html`, então apenas altere a linha do seu código atual em `html` de:

`<form action="#" method="post">`

Para:

`<form action="enviar.php" method="post">`

## [Veja o código em funcionamento](http://solutionsagencia.com.br/testephp3).

Caso queira colocar seu email, eu atualizo o código para que veja como a mensagem chega no seu email.

Ficando assim:

```
<form action="enviar.php" method="post">
<div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="name" placeholder="Seu Nome">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="email" placeholder="Seu E-mail">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="subject" placeholder="Assunto">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <textarea name="message" cols="1" rows="1" class="message" placeholder="Sua mensagem..." id="message"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Enviar Mensagem" id="submit" class="button templatemo_sendbtn">
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Agora crie uma nova página com nome `enviar.php` e coloque dentro dela o seguinte código:

```
<?php

    $para = "seuemail@email.com";
    $name = $_POST['message'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $mensagem = "Nome: $name<br>";
    $mensagem .= "Email: $email<br>";
    $mensagem .= "Assunto: $subject<br>";
    $mensagem .= "Mensagem: $message<br>";
    $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n". 'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

    if (mail($para, $subject, $mensagem, $headers)){
        echo "Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso!";
    }
    else{
        echo "Aconteceu um erro, tente novamente mais tarde.";
    }

?>
```

Obs: Caso queira ajuda utilizando o `PHPMailer` nós podemos ajudar também.

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar assim:

```
<?php
//if "email" variable is filled out, send email
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {

//Email information
$admin_email = "someone@example.com";
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$comment = $_REQUEST['comment'];

//send email
mail($admin_email, "$subject", $comment, "From:" . $email);

//Email response
echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
}

?>
```

Note que no exemplo é usado o Request, mas pode usar o $_POST.

Comment: Onde coloco esse código? Dentro do meu index e dentro de
<script> ?

Comment: Esse codigo que eu apresentei, é para onde o seu botao vai apontar.
Por favor edite a sua pergunta e coloque o seu codigo HTML com o seu formulario. Depois eu ajudo com o codigo.

Answer (score 1):

O plugin [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) implementa todos os métodos PHP necessários para que você consiga enviar o e-mail.

Clicando [aqui](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example) você pode ver um exemplo que resolve exatamente seu problema.

Em resumo:

**1.** Baixe o plugin.

**2.** Adicione ao seu projeto.

**3.** Crie um arquivo IGUAL ao [desse exemplo](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example).

**4.** Na action do seu form, coloque caminho para o arquivo que vocẽ criou no passo *3* (algo como `action="php/enviar-email.php"`)

Isso deve funcionar. Caso não funcione, comente na minha resposta :)